# How can I parse JSON in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, json

I want to use Perl script that gets the JSON data and converts it into XML file. How can I do that in Perl?

Comment: http://json.org/ links to http://search.cpan.org/search?query=JSON

Comment: Don't put in jokey tags. It makes it a lot harder for people to find questions and answers.

Comment: @Alex Reynolds: Some questions deserve answers and some do not. Specifically, *send-me-teh-codez* type questions do not. Sometimes, however, the question can be salvaged. In this case, after a second consideration, I decided to fix up the question. In the future, you may also want to fix the question as well as editing the tags. As for my attitude as to when a question should be fixed versus left to languish, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24838/are-you-less-likely-to-down-vote-someone-whose-gravatar-is-a-photograph-of-them/24862#24862

Answer (score 14):

```
use JSON;

my $json_string = '................';

my $deserialized = from_json( $json_string );
```

That's all - your JSON data is parsed and stored in $deserialized.

Comment: If performance is at all a concern, also install JSON::XS (JSON will use it if it's there...no code changes needed).

Comment: Well, sure it doesn't. There is no information how the xml should look (for example: what should be attribute, and what tag), so it's impossible to build xml out of data without schema specification. If schema is "any, just make it valid" - `use XML::Simple; print XMLout( $deserialized );`

Answer (score 10):

Install: [XML::XML2JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::XML2JSON) with

> sudo cpan XML::XML2JSON

and then try:

```
use XML::XML2JSON;
my $JSON = '{"entry":{"name":"Douglas Crockford","phone":"555 123 456"}}';
my $XML2JSON = XML::XML2JSON->new();
my $Obj = $XML2JSON->json2obj($JSON);
my $XML = $XML2JSON->obj2xml($Obj);
print $XML;
```